# "Done" UIBarButtonItem not displaying on number pad (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a "Done" button to a text field.

The black UIToolbar *is* displaying, but the "Done" button is not.

In the attributes inspector, 'Return key' is set to 'Done' and 'Auto-enable Return Key' is enabled.

The UITextField is connected to the delegate

This is inside a UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class itemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var itemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var itemInput: UITextField!

var textFieldIsBeingEdited: Bool = false
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    itemInput.delegate = self

    self.addDoneButtonToKeyboard()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func addDoneButtonToKeyboard(){
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: itemInput, action: Selector("doneButtonAction"))

    let items = NSMutableArray()
    items.addObject(flexSpace)
    items.addObject(done)

    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    itemInput.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}


func doneButtonAction()
{
    self.itemInput.resignFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: You created `items` but you never added those items to the `doneToolbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to add the `items` to your `let doneToolbar: UIToolbar`

```
doneToolbar.items = items as [AnyObject]
```

**brief answer**

```
 items.addObject(flexSpace)
 items.addObject(done)
 doneToolbar.items = items as [AnyObject]
 doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
 itemInput.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you.

I had to change to
     doneToolbar.items = items as? [UIBarButtonItem]